# Having a problem with the Grid height inside scrollviewer WPF XAML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am having a problem with Grid height inside scrollviewer. I am binding my grid height with the scrollviewer. And if I give it the fixed height then it just breaks the layout of the grid when I run the application on different devices. Normally, grid height should increase dynamically when I add more content to it but it is just fixed and all of the content is getting shinked.

Below I have attached some part of my code.

[Here is the image where the height is binded with the scrollviewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3aRD.png)

[In this image, I gave a fixed height 400 and it shows what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfZbO.png)

[This is the image of application and it just does not have the same design as in the XAML Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5nTK.png)

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollviewer" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="7" Grid.ColumnSpan="7" Grid.RowSpan="20" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">

        <Grid x:Name="GridInputs" Height="400" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.4*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.4*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.3*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.3*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.3*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.3*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.3*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.3*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.3*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.3*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.3*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.3*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.3*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.3*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.3*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.3*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.3*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.3*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.3*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.3*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!-- Row 1 -->
            <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" BorderBrush="Black" Grid.ColumnSpan="7" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5"/>
            <!--<Viewbox Grid.Row="6"  Grid.Column="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" x:Name="vbLongest">-->
            <Grid Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Viewbox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" StretchDirection="DownOnly" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <!--<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Ground height to AHP" FontSize="5" Foreground="Black"/>-->
                    <Label Content="Ground Height to AHP Z" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" />
                </Viewbox>
                <Viewbox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" StretchDirection="DownOnly">
                    <Label x:Name="GroundHeight" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Ground height to AHP" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Gray"/>
                </Viewbox>
            </Grid>
            <!--</Viewbox>-->
            <Viewbox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Margin="2">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Z" FontSize="20" Foreground="Black"/>
            </Viewbox>
            <Viewbox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Margin="2">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="=" FontSize="20" Foreground="Black"/>
            </Viewbox>
            <TextBox x:Name="tbGroundZ" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="0" Margin="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding CurrentPackage[BuckHeightZ].Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"
                         FontSize="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Grid}, Converter={StaticResource fontSizeCon}}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Have you tried not setting the height of the grid? I believe the grid should automatically expand to fit inside the scrollviewer.

Comment: Yes, I also have tried not setting the height but it destroys the layout and every row is super big then.

Comment: In your grid set the rowdefinitions to auto, and then add an extra row with * height - it’ll folk out the remaining space.

Comment: Ah just looked a bit closer at your XAML. 

I don’t think you should do height of rows the way you do it. 

Try doing auto row height, or a fixed height and * the last row like i mentioned above. 

Are you aware of how *x works?

Comment: I just tried your methods still it does not work. Design layout breaks, some rows are big and some rows are small. Also there is no gap in between rows which is I am giving 0.1* in height. Also I am not an expert with XAML but I know how * works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding viewbox after scrollviewer and moving all of the grid into the viewbox, solved my issue. Now, I can give any fixed height and width to my grid and it does not break the design.

Viewbox stretch and scale the child elements according to the display resolution or dimensions.